# Show error message if two textboxes are empty

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I have two textboxes, and I would like to display an error message if the user does not enter any information and they are empty.
I have this code (but only works for one):

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    var dialog = new MessageDialog("Error");
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

I've tried this, but it does not work:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text || textBox2.Text))
{
    var dialog = new MessageDialog("Error");
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This condition is not valid for `||`operator, as `||` operator expects boolean as their operands.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text || textBox2.Text)
```

So this should throw error saying

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

If you want to show the error message when *anyone of textbox is empty*:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)
```

If you want to show the error message when *both of textboxes are empty*:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Less performant but interesting none the less for other ways of thinking (and will probably help you solve other non-string related tasks in the same manner) You can concatinate (add) the text boxes together and check for null or Empty. if both are empty, it will execute the if block, if 1 or both have any text, it will not enter the if block

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text + textbox2.Text))
{
    //Stuff
}
```

This uses Logic Gate thinking... in this instance "OR"

[Bedtime reading](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/logic-gate-AND-OR-XOR-NOT-NAND-NOR-and-XNOR)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this.

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))
{
    var dialog = new MessageDialog("Error");
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

I prefere `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `IsNullOrEmpty` because it although checks if the string contains only white spaces. 
You can chain as many conditions as you want. `||` stands for or and `&&` for and.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) | String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
```

this will solve.

Comment: " | " this will check conditions 1 and 2, even if 1 is already true. rest of the answers has "  | |  " used in if conditions.